# Who is wrong, the book or me? (C two dimensional array)

Tags: c, arrays

I read a book about C and there is an example there about pointing to a two-dimensional array and printing the values of the array.

The example in the book is:

```
main(){
    int s[5][2] = {
        { 1234, 56 },
        { 1212, 33 },
        { 1434, 80 },
        { 1312, 78 }
    } ;

    int ( *p )[2] ;
    int i, j, *pint ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 3 ; i++ )
    {
        p = &s[i] ;
        pint = p ;
        printf ( "\n" ) ;
        for ( j = 0 ; j <= 1 ; j++ )
            printf ( "%d ", *( pint + j ) ) ;
    }
}
```

I made my version for this code and I observed that in the book code he declared a `[5][2]` array and I declared a `[4][2]` array and we have the same result.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int arr[4][2]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
  int (*p)[2];
  int i=0,x=0,*pint;
  while(i<=3){
    x=0;
    p=&arr[i];
    pint=p;
    i++;
    while(x<2){
      printf("%d",*(pint+x));
      x++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're both wrong, since:

```
pint = p;
```

is an error. Your compiler should at least warn about this. The code should be:

```
pint = *p;
```

Your loop structure is harder to follow than the book's one, and you don't put a space between numbers.

You seem to be asking about the change from `int arr[5][2]` to `int arr[4][2]`.  The original isn't wrong. You don't have to use every element of an array you declared. The book had an array with 5 rows but only used 4 of them, that's fine.

Comment: Thank you. Another question is, if I want to loop and I don't know the length of the array, how I find the length of this array?

Comment: With C, unless you you are using malloc, you have to know the length of the array beforehand. Show an example of where you don't know the length of the array.

Comment: To find the length of an *array* you can do `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]`.  Note that this doesn't work for things which are not arrays.